# CSS + JS. Если поменять свойство overflow с hidden на scroll на элементе в рантайме, то чтобы сделать скролл, мне нужно будет переместить мышь

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка

Опишу пример: у меня есть список, который должен начать скроллиться после того, как я прокручу своё колёсико мыши 5 раз. Для этого я сделал счётчик, который начинает увеличиваться, когда срабатывает событие `wheel`. После того, как значение счётчика станет равным 5, для списка я меняю свойство `overflow: hidden` на `overflow: scroll`. Всё работает, но есть одна проблема. После того, как я поменял свойство `overflow` на `scroll`, мне нужно чуть сдвинуть курсор мыши, чтобы я мог начать делать скролл при помощи колёсика мыши. Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Что ж ты там такое кодишь...5 скроллов мыши, два нажатия клавиши,  супер-мего-сейфо доступ?) .... А если серьезно, попробуй после смены состояния скролла повесить события на перемещение вьюпорта на 1рх вниз... может поможет

Comment: @BlackStar1991 На самом деле, моя ситуация совсем отличается от той, которую я описал выше. Просто подумал, что так будет легче объяснить, что мне нужно

Comment: Очень похоже на задачу с бесконечным скроллом, с погрузкой контента.... но это настолько заезженная тема что прям противно. Да и если я прав и у вас сайт который зависит от seo продвижения то советую сразу отказаться от этой фичи....

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Нет, задача заключается совсем в другом. У меня есть два div. Первый - шапка, второй - список. Логика должна быть такая: когда я начинаю делать скролл списка, сам список скроллиться не должен. Сначала должна схлопнуться шапка, а уже после того, как шапка схлопнулась, нужно включить скролл для самого списка. Но когда я проделываю действие с тем, чтобы включать scroll для списка, то для того, чтобы список начал скроллиться, мне нужно пошевелить курсором.

Comment: сложно визуализировать такие вещи, лучше прикреплять тестовый код если надо решение, но такое впечатление что задача решается не тем путем.